# Cannot instantiate the type Path2D

Tags: java, path-2d

I am trying to create a drawing of a triangle with the path2D class and when I try to create my triangle, it says that "Cannot instantiate the type Path2D", I'm not really sure what I did wrong here if anyone can help.

```
package houseGoesVroom;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class HousePlans 
{
    //instance variables
    private int x;
    private int y;
    
    //constructor
    public HousePlans(int cornerX, int cornerY)
    {
        x = cornerX;
        y = cornerY;
    }
    
    //draw method
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2)
    {
        int r = (int) (256 * Math.random());
        int g = (int) (256 * Math.random());
        int b = (int) (256 * Math.random());
        
        g2.fillRect(0, 40, 80, 120);
        
        Path2D path = new Path2D();
        path.moveTo(0,40);
        path.lineTo(40,0);
        path.lineTo(80, 40); 
        path.closePath();
        g2.draw(path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Path2D` is an abstract class. You can not create object of an abstract class or interface. There are two concrete implementations of `Path2D` inside `Path2D` class. [Path2D.Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html) and [Path2D.Float](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Float.html). You can use any of them based on your precision level of your coordinates.

```java
Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
```